# setImageBitmap on onPostExecute freeze my listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I'm following the instructions from here [Android Smooth Scrolling](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)  to get an smooth scrolling, but the method setImageBitmap on the onPostExecute still freezing my listview. Here my code for the async task

```
private static class ThumbnailTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public ThumbnailTask(ImageView imageView) {

        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        Bitmap image =  fragment.getAlbum().getPhotos().get(params[0]).getImage(Utils.THUMBNAIL_SCREEN_SIZE);
        return ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(image, 40, 40);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }




}
```

And here is how I'm using it on the getView method

```
 new ThumbnailTask(holder.image).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, position);
```

The long process is the "getImage" from the doInBackground method, and I'm just puting the image on the ImageView on the onPostExecute. If I comment the setImageBitmap, the scroll get smooth again. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing it in the Ui thread?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to have the get() in your async task.  I think that you can't see the negative effects of the get when you comment out this line:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

but it is not the problem.

I'd recommend this:

```
private static class ThumbnailTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private final ImageView yourImageView = null;
    public ThumbnailTask(ImageView imageView) {

        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        Bitmap image =  fragment.getAlbum().getPhotos().get(params[0]).getImage(Utils.THUMBNAIL_SCREEN_SIZE);
        return ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(image, 40, 40);
        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            yourImageView = imageViewReference.get();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```